# Today little moody. as it was raining yesterday

Tags: grammaticality

I was asked a question like "How is climate there?"

What should I reply?

> Today little moody. as it was raining yesterday.

or

> Today little moody. as it rained yesterday.

Comment: The weather is rarely "moody." People can be moody because of the weather. You might consider "variable," or perhaps you mean "cloudy." I have no idea what you mean by "moody" weather.

Comment: I suggest: **capricious weather** or **the weather is capricious**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **neither**. You could try these:

> - The weather today is a little moody as it was raining yesterday.
> - The weather today is a little moody as it was rained yesterday.
> - The weather appears to be a little moody today, as it had rained yesterday.
> - Today's weather seems to be bit moody as it rained yesterday.

**Note**: There are many ways to say the same. These are only a few suggestions.